# How to search a field in CKAN

Tags: python-2.7, ckan

I am adding a new field in the ckan_dataset.json. And i want to be able to also search by this field when i search in the default search box.

The logical thing would be to include the field_name some place, but I'm not able to find where.

I also know that it searches by title by default so I have tried to find where it does that, but with no success.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If your dataset is private you will not be able to search it. So, my advice is making the dataset public in order to make your new fields searchable by default.

Well I understand that the system is made to cover general purposes as a public Open Data Catalog. If your organization needs to have a hidden visibility for some datasets, I recommend you to check out the different options for membership and see which fits in best. You can alter the permissions, although adding in new permissions levels are not currently easy.